# Bootstrap index download failing in sonarQube job from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

When I am running sonarQube job in jenkins, it shows console output as in image. While downloading boot strap index, it shows an error as sonarQube server cannot be reached, but I am able to connect to that server from my local PC using that URL. Can anyone give me solution for this.

[image: Image with output.]

Comment: Check if the machine running Jenkins has access to SonarQube. For example, login to the Jenkins machine, and try to run analyze any project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above problem has resolved by doing two things
1) Installed java in sonarqube server that is accessible from jenkins
2) Installed right certificates